# How do I extract parts of a function from a function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to take a function of type `(Either a b -> c)` as a parameter and pass its methods f and g that it uses depending on the variable type in the form `(f, g)`, but I'm not sure how to do so.

In another but related problem, I'm also trying to take a function of type `(a -> (b, c))` and return both its methods in the form `(a -> b, a -> c)`. But I really have no idea which method to use. I've tried reading around, but maybe I don't know how to properly word the issue.

If any of you know what category specifically this type of thing in Haskell goes under I'd appreciate it so I can read up on it. Thanks in advance for any help.

Given that I don't have any clue how I'm supposed to do this, anything I've tried has been nonsense.

Comment: Try extracting one function at a time, so e.g. write a function with the type `(Either a b -> c) -> a -> c`.

Comment: Say you want to go from `a` to `c`, and you already have a way to go from `Either a b` to `c`.  So what's missing ? and who does just that ?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, figured out how to solve both. Not sure if it's optimal but used a couple of helper methods for the first one for the cases of Left a or Right b being passed, then just combined those methods with the (Either a b -> c) one. For the last one I also made some helper methods to extract the key and value out of a tuple, and combined them with the (a -> (b, c)) function using the dot operator.

Comment: Great, congratulations ! Note that according to SO rules, you may answer your own question for the enlightenment of other users. You may even, after a decent interval, accept your own answer and gain the relevant bit of reputation.

Answer (score 2):

The two problems are similar.

As for the first problem, you want to end up with (among other stuff) a function of type `a->c`. You're starting from one of type `Either a b -> c`. So you need to compose that input function (on the right side) with one of type `a -> Either a b`. You can either guess, or ask [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a+-%3E+Either+a+b&scope=set%3Astackage) for the answer: it is the `Left` constructor that does this for you.

The `b->c` part can be solved in exactly the same way, so we end up with:

```
getComponentFunctionsA :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a->c, b->c)
getComponentFunctionsA f = (f . Left, f . Right)
```

As for the second problem, we need to compose the input function of type `a -> (b, c)` on the *left* side with the library provided pair component extractors: [fst](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a%2Cb%29-%3Ea&scope=set%3Astackage) and [`snd`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a%2Cb%29-%3Eb&scope=set%3Astackage).

That gives us:

```
getComponentFunctionsB :: (a -> (b, c)) -> (a -> b, a -> c)
getComponentFunctionsB f = (fst . f, snd . f)
```

### Point-free versions:

In functional programming, there is a programming style known as [Point-free Programming (PFP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming), where you define new functions primarily as composition of older functions, and do not need to name/use any input variables.

We seem to have a good case for PFP here. So should we want to define the above functions using point-free style, we can do it for example by importing the infix  [`(&&&)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) operator from the `Control.Arrow` module, specializing its polymorphic type to:

```
(&&&) :: (b -> c) -> (b -> d) -> (b -> (c, d))
```

Our two functions can then be rewritten like this:

```
import  Control.Arrow((&&&))

getComponentFunctionsA :: (Either a b -> c) -> (a->c, b->c)
getComponentFunctionsA = (. Left)  &&&  (. Right)

getComponentFunctionsB :: (a -> (b, c)) -> (a -> b, a -> c)
getComponentFunctionsB = (fst .)  &&&  (snd .)
```

Note the absence of any variable names in this code.